# Filling missing data with historical mean fast and efficiently in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, na, missing-data

I am working with a large panel dataset (longitudinal data) with 500k observations. Currently, I am trying to fill the missing data (at most 30% of observations) using the mean of up till time t of each variable. (The reason why I do not fill the data with overall mean, is to avoid a forward looking bias that arises from using data only available at a later point in time.)

I wrote the following function which does the job, but runs extremely slow (5 hours for 500k rows!!) In general, I find that filling missing data in Pandas is a computationally tedious task. **Please enlighten me on how you normally fill missing values, and how you make it run fast**

Function to fill with mean till time "t":

```
def meanTillTimeT(x,cols):
    start = time.time()
    print('Started')
    x.reset_index(inplace=True)
    for i in cols:
        l1 =[]
        for j in range(x.shape[0]):
            if x.loc[j,i] !=0 and np.isnan(x.loc[j,i]) == False :
                l1.append(x.loc[j,i])
            elif np.isnan(x.loc[j,i])==True :
                x.loc[j,i]=np.mean(l1)      
    end = time.time()
    print("time elapsed:", end - start)
    return x
```

Comment: This will obviously be far more compute-intenstive than most other ways of filling; you might like to introduce a max window length over which we compute mean (then you could also do filling in chunks, parallelize etc.). Also, there doesn't seem to be a standard term for this approach but I think a good term this ***"filling with forward mean"***. (It's not called *"forward-filling"* because that only means *"last observation carried forward (locf)"*)

Comment: Eventually, after you've processed some amount X% of the dataset, this will become numerically roughly equivalent to imputing with the overall mean (within a certain accuracy), but still far more compute-intensive. How much accuracy do you actually need, and are you sure you really want to do this? I understand your point about bias, but people generally don't do this, I suspect you don't really need to do it. Example: you could process things in chunks, take the backward-looking average for all previous chunks, and fill it simultaneously to the entire current chunk.

Comment: ...The optimal chunk size (tradeoff of accuracy vs efficiency) is up to you. Probably you want to logarithmically increase teh chunk size.

Comment: ...other than the obvious speedup in going from manual iteration to `cumsum()` as @olivaw shows.

Comment: So my above comments depend on the distribution of your data being fairly stationary. If you expect a major discontinuity or non-stationarity, then handle the chunk windowing differently.

Comment: You have some good points. Accuracy means quite a lot. I am trying to figure out how to use cumsum.

Comment: Chris, it helps if you show us a typical range (mean-median-stdev-25%ile-75%ile-min-max) of one your series. How much % accuracy do you really need? 10% 0.0001%?

Comment: What would you do instead then? Just rely on overall mean, even though you know it has a bias? To me it seems odd to do so?

Comment: I already told you: **use a (computationally-efficient proxy to) the backward-looking mean, computed (using `cumsum()`) over logarithmically-increasing chunk sizes.** Just don't try to precisely compute every single itty-bitty backward-looking mean for every single row of the dataset, which will be ~O(N^2), or at least O(MN) where M is the number of missing/NA rows.

Comment: i really like your answers, but could you please provide me with a toy example of how to implement it?

Comment: Ok, will do by tomorrow. Can you please post us some seeded-random code that generates sample data with your pameters (mean-median-stdev-25%ile-75%ile-min-max) of one your series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us build a DataFrame for illustration:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"value1": [1, 2, 1, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 3],
                   "value2": [0, 8, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 9, np.nan]})
```

Here is the DataFrame:

```
      value1  value2
   0     1.0     0.0
   1     2.0     8.0
   2     1.0     1.0
   3     5.0     NaN
   4     NaN     NaN
   5     NaN     8.0
   6     8.0     9.0
   7     3.0     NaN
```

Now, I suggest to first compute the cumulative sums using [pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and also the number of non-NaNs values so as to compute the means. After that, it is enough to fill the NaNs with those means, and inserting them in the original DataFrame. Both actions use [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), which is going to be much much faster than Python loops:

```
df_mean = df.cumsum() / (~df.isna()).cumsum()
df_mean = df_mean.fillna(method = "ffill")
df = df.fillna(value = df_mean)
```

The result is:

```
      value1  value2
   0    1.00     0.0
   1    2.00     8.0
   2    1.00     1.0
   3    5.00     3.0
   4    2.25     3.0
   5    2.25     8.0
   6    8.00     9.0
   7    3.00     5.2
```

Comment: The solution sounds good, but how will you do it for longitudinal data??

Comment: What is the issue? You might want to sort the DataFrame first (e.g., by date and by people) with sort_values. You may also need to apply the computations only to certain columns, which are easily selected in a DataFrame. Is there anything special that I am missing?

Comment: So when sorting on data forexample, will nans occur at the bottom of a particular date? Because otherwise, the cumsum won't contain all the numbers of that particular date when filling the nan.

Comment: You need to be more specific. In your example code, I see no sign of dates or panel/people. At a given date, you want to make sure to average over all data from previous dates and all available date from the current date?

Comment: X is a dataframe consisting of multiple firms, at multiple time instances. Not all firms are there all the time. I want to make sure that I average over all current and past dates.

Comment: You want to average over all current and past dates for each firm independently or you want to average over all firms?

Comment: Over all firms, otherwise I will still have nans if the firm never had a value before.

Comment: So you can use the code I proposed after sorting all values, which might be a bit slow---test it. Sort with ```df = df.sort_values(list(df.columns))```, making sure that the date is the first column. The NaNs will be put at the end of each date, so that they will be replaced by the average over all dates (previous and current) and all firms.

Comment: The method is extremely slow and computationally exhaustive. It crashes for any dataframe of non-toy size.